# Google maps: Управление камерой при перемещении маркера на карте (android)

Tags: java, android

Вообщем, при открытии карты я получаю местоположения юзера, все гуд, но при перемещении маркера камера перемешается на новое место,а потом обратно на текущее местоположение. Необходимо при установке маркера на новую позицию перемещать камеру корректно(без возврата на местоположение) и получать координаты маркера.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.draggable(true);

    markerOptions.title("Ваше местоположение");
    markerOptions
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    //stop location updates
    //if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
   // }
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Creating a marker

            mMap.clear();
            MarkerOptions marker =
                    new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude))
                            .title("Текущее местоположение");


            // Animating to the touched position
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.addMarker(marker);

        }
    });

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: кажется, что у тебя самый нижний animateCamera() получает не тот параметр.

Comment: @tse
т.е передавать нужно другие данные?

Comment: вопрос актуален!